# Dataset Graph with separate hashes per table

Tags: ruby, sequel

The Sequel documentation states that

> Dataset graphing changes the dataset to yield hashes where keys are table
>     name symbols and values are hashes representing the columns related to
>     that table. https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib/sequel/dataset/graph.rb#L5

I'd really like to use this behaviour, so when I do something like;

```
db[:referrals].graph(:users, :id => :user_id).first
```

I would get;

```
{referrals: {id: 1, name: 'Joe', user_id: 10}, users: {id: 10, name: 'Dave'}}
```

However, what is returned is more like;

```
{id: 1, name: 'Joe', user_id: 10, users_name: 'Dave'}
```

I can't see any obvious way to change this in the docs. Am I missing something blindingly obvious (wouldn't be the first time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs need to be updated (I'll take care of that shortly).  You now need to use the `graph_each` extension to get the splitting.

Comment: Ah, that's what I needed. Thanks for clearing that up Jeremy. And thanks for Sequel, it is an awesome library.